# i cant catkin_make moveit_simple_grasps in ROS jade

Tags: ros, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

i cant install  moveit_simple_grasps in ROS jade

```
[ 96%] Built target moveit_visual_tools_demo
In file included from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:44:0,
                 from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/simple_grasps.h:60,
                 from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/grasp_filter.h:49,
                 from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/grasp_filter.cpp:35:
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1042:23: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   std::string name_ = "visual_tools";
                       ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1046:38: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool pub_rviz_markers_connected_ = false;
                                      ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1047:35: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool pub_rviz_markers_waited_ = false;
                                   ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1057:36: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool batch_publishing_enabled_ = true;;
                                    ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1086:28: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool psychedelic_mode_ = false;
                            ^
In file included from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:44:0,
                 from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/simple_grasps.h:60,
                 from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/simple_grasps.cpp:35:
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1042:23: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   std::string name_ = "visual_tools";
                       ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1046:38: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool pub_rviz_markers_connected_ = false;
                                      ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1047:35: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool pub_rviz_markers_waited_ = false;
                                   ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1057:36: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool batch_publishing_enabled_ = true;;
                                    ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1092:9: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 typedef std::shared_ptr<RvizVisualTools> RvizVisualToolsPtr;
         ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1093:9: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 typedef std::shared_ptr<const RvizVisualTools> RvizVisualToolsConstPtr;
         ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1086:28: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool psychedelic_mode_ = false;
                            ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1092:9: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 typedef std::shared_ptr<RvizVisualTools> RvizVisualToolsPtr;
         ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/rviz_visual_tools/include/rviz_visual_tools/rviz_visual_tools.h:1093:9: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 typedef std::shared_ptr<const RvizVisualTools> RvizVisualToolsConstPtr;
         ^
In file included from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/simple_grasps.h:60:0,
                 from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/grasp_filter.h:49,
                 from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/grasp_filter.cpp:35:
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:600:34: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool mannual_trigger_update_ = false;
                                  ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:635:43: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool robot_state_root_offset_enabled_ = false;
                                           ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:642:9: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 typedef std::shared_ptr<MoveItVisualTools> MoveItVisualToolsPtr;
         ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:643:9: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 typedef std::shared_ptr<const MoveItVisualTools> MoveItVisualToolsConstPtr;
         ^
In file included from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/grasp_filter.h:49:0,
                 from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/grasp_filter.cpp:35:
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/simple_grasps.h:84:3: error: ‘MoveItVisualToolsPtr’ in namespace ‘moveit_visual_tools’ does not name a type
   moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualToolsPtr visual_tools_;
   ^
In file included from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/grasp_filter.h:49:0,
                 from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/grasp_filter.cpp:35:
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/simple_grasps.h:98:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘rviz_tools’
   SimpleGrasps(moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualToolsPtr rviz_tools, bool verbose = false);
                                                          ^
In file included from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/grasp_filter.cpp:35:0:
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/grasp_filter.h:122:3: error: ‘MoveItVisualToolsPtr’ in namespace ‘moveit_visual_tools’ does not name a type
   moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualToolsPtr visual_tools_;
   ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/grasp_filter.h:130:26: error: ‘moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualToolsPtr’ has not been declared
     moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualToolsPtr& visual_tools );
                          ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/grasp_filter.cpp:46:24: error: ‘moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualToolsPtr’ has not been declared
   moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualToolsPtr& visual_tools ):
                        ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/grasp_filter.cpp: In constructor ‘moveit_simple_grasps::GraspFilter::GraspFilter(moveit::core::RobotState, int&)’:
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/grasp_filter.cpp:48:3: error: class ‘moveit_simple_grasps::GraspFilter’ does not have any field named ‘visual_tools_’
   visual_tools_(visual_tools),
   ^
In file included from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/simple_grasps.h:60:0,
                 from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/simple_grasps.cpp:35:
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:600:34: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool mannual_trigger_update_ = false;
                                  ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:635:43: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   bool robot_state_root_offset_enabled_ = false;
                                           ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:642:9: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 typedef std::shared_ptr<MoveItVisualTools> MoveItVisualToolsPtr;
         ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:643:9: error: ‘shared_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 typedef std::shared_ptr<const MoveItVisualTools> MoveItVisualToolsConstPtr;
         ^
In file included from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/simple_grasps.cpp:35:0:
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/simple_grasps.h:84:3: error: ‘MoveItVisualToolsPtr’ in namespace ‘moveit_visual_tools’ does not name a type
   moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualToolsPtr visual_tools_;
   ^
In file included from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/simple_grasps.cpp:35:0:
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/simple_grasps.h:98:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘rviz_tools’
   SimpleGrasps(moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualToolsPtr rviz_tools, bool verbose = false);
                                                          ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/simple_grasps.cpp:41:27: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 SimpleGrasps::SimpleGrasps(moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualToolsPtr visual_tools, bool verbose) :
                           ^
/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/simple_grasps.cpp:328:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 } // namespace
 ^
make[2]: *** [moveit_simple_grasps/CMakeFiles/moveit_simple_grasps.dir/src/simple_grasps.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [moveit_simple_grasps/CMakeFiles/moveit_simple_grasps.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [moveit_simple_grasps/CMakeFiles/moveit_simple_grasps_filter.dir/src/grasp_filter.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [moveit_simple_grasps/CMakeFiles/moveit_simple_grasps_filter.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246663/i-cant-catkin_make-moveit_simple_grasps-in-ros-jade/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-28**:
Please use the *Preformatted Text* button next time when copy/pasting console output (errors), launch files, code snippets, etc. It makes things much easier to read.

Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-28**:
Also: this is not the entire error message, just the last bit of it. Without the lines leading to what you already included, it's going to be very hard to help you. Please update your question by editing it. Use the *edit* button/link for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a problem with `moveit_simple_grasps`:

> ```
> [..]
> ```

```
In file included from /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws2/src/moveit_visual_tools/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h:44:0,
[..]
```

This looks like you're trying to compile a C++11 version of `moveit_visual_tools` on an OS that doesn't have a compiler that supports that.

If you are on Jade, make sure you are not trying to compile the `kinetic-devel` branch of [davetcoleman/moveit_visual_tools](https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_visual_tools).

Note btw that `moveit_visual_tools` has been released for Jade (see [status_page/ros_jade_default.html?q=visual_tools](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_jade_default.html?q=visual_tools)), no need to build that all from source. Just `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-moveit-visual-tools`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-03-06**:
Respected @gvdhoorn, I am also having the same issue. I am using ROS indigo. I used the command "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-visual-tools" But unfortunately, the problem remain intact. I tried both of your mentioned links but I am still unable to cakin_make the "moveit_simple_grasps"

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-06**:
If you've installed the binary package, then you don't need to build `moveit_visual_tools` anymore.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-03-06**:
Thank you fr such a quick reply. But then i need to build the package of "moveit_simple_grasps". Isn't so? or do i need to simple try with the launch files of "moveit_simple_grasps"?? bcz while building this package, i getting the same error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-06**:
If you need to build `moveit_simple_grasps` then you'll need to make sure all dependencies are installed, and make sure you are building the correct version for your ROS version. It's probably better to open a new question for this.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-03-06**:
Will do the needful.
Regards